# Search a file system for files that match a given pattern

Tags: python, optimization, search, file-system

My concerns with this code:

1. Is there a more efficient way to find files by pattern in Python?
2. Does `os.walk()` work in Windows?
3. Is this code pythonic?
4. Should `search()` be broken down into 2 functions?
5. Is it stupid to handle IOError exception by printing the error msg to the console?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

'''
Finding files by pattern
'''

import os
import fnmatch
from os.path import join


def search(base, patt):
    ''' Yield files that match a given pattern '''
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(base):
        try:
            for _ in [join(root, _) for _ in files if fnmatch.fnmatch(_, patt)]:
                yield _
        except IOError as error:
            print error


def example_use(d, p):
    ''' Example use of search function '''
    for _ in search(d, p):
        print _


if __name__ == '__main__':
    example_use('/var', '*.log')
```

Comment: Please no advice on using unix tools like: 
"sed awk grep egrep find"

Answer (score 2):

Looks quite pythonic. However:

- `_` stands for *don't care*, akin to famous [hunoz](https://github.com/cslarsen/mickey-scheme/blob/master/test/test-maclisp.scm). It is not expected to be used in expressions later on; it is a placeholder.

Fot instance, I am totally lost in what

```
        for _ in [join(root, _) for _ in files if fnmatch.fnmatch(_, patt)]:
            yield _
```

does actually yield.

- `os.walk()` works perfectly well on Windows
- I don't see how do you want to break `search` into two functions. What would those functions do?
- Any usable file matcher should have an option to specify file type (plain vs directory vs link vs etc), attributes, etc.